# How to use Mongodb with Fable?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm new to F# and Fable and I'm trying to create a Mongodb collection from a Fable's compiled code.

How can I express this code in F# to compile with Fable?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to some of the source of some fable import libs, [fable-import-d3](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-graphics/blob/master/bindings/fable-import-d3/Fable.Import.D3.fs#L330) and [fable-import-pixi](https://gist.github.com/davidtme/cb3d58024c2fdfa0cc6acca45cbbabff#file-fable-import-pixi-fs-L179), the `Import` attribute allows for JS libs to be used directly. The caveat to that is that you are mapping the imported JS to an F# type.

**SIDE NOTE**

There does not appear to be a lib for mongodb and fable, e.g. fable-import-mongodb